# Data structure to store HashMap in Druid

Tags: java, druid

I am newbie in Druid. My problem is that how to store and query HashMap in Druid using java to interact. 
I have `network table` as follow:

```
Network    f1    f1    f3  .... fn
value       1    3      2  ..... 2
```

Additional, I have `range-time table`

```
time             impression
2016-08-10-00      1000
2016-08-10-00      3000
2016-08-10-00      4000
2016-08-10-00      2000
2016-08-10-00      8000
```

In Druid can I store `range-time` table as a `HashMap` and query both of the tables above with the statement:

```
Filter f1 = 1 and f2 = 1 and range-time between [t1, t2].
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@VanThaoNguye,

Yes you can store the hashmaps in druid and you can query with bound filters.

You can read more about bound filters here: http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/filters.html#bound-filter

Comment: Please improve your answer by posting actual code as reference. Hyperlinks will die some day, or the content shifts to another url. For posterity's sake we highly recommend to include the code in your answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, but to day. I am expert on druid. Your answer is acceptable but late. Druid takes advances on storage historical data and time series query.

Comment: Being late is fine.  S/O is to share the knowledge.  It helps late comers like me.  Having said that I do not understand this answer.  How do you store hashmaps?

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi
Just pass the JSON Object. Let's say you have JS Object like the below one.

var x = { event_type: 'hello', event_properties': { product: { id: 23432, name: 2342 } }, user: { id: 2342, mail: 'xyz@xyz.com' } };

y = JSON.stringify(x);

and then you pass y as the message to kafka, then tranquility kafka reads it stores it. (Realtime). You can do the same thing in batch processing.

Comment: my experience is I had to use `flattenSpec` to convert the nested objects to a flat key-value pairs object.  Without the flattenSpec Druid picks up the top level keys only.